# How to run user-data commands in Cloudformation on EC2 as some other user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

What I have noticed is whenever user-data commands are executed while executing a Cloudformation template to spin up an EC2, they are run via the root user. How can I change this behaviour so that the commands are run as ec2-user?

I tried doing a

```
sudo su ec2-user
```

to tackle this, but that apparently opens up another shell on the machine so doesn't really solve this use case.

Comment: If you are simply wanting to create files that belong to another user, remember that the User Data script runs as `root`, so the script can create files anywhere on the disk. Be sure to `chown` files to their future owner.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` has the `-u` parameter that lets you choose the user. So you can use:

```
sudo -u ec2-user echo hello from ec2-user
```